# What does a 10 above a figured bass symbol mean?

Tags: voice-leading

I am going to guess here and say that the tenor will be a 10th above the bass but not sure.. can someone please confirm? perhaps it means the Soprano is a 10th above?

[image]

Comment: Could be this indicates to the accompnist to play the r.h. in 3rd position: starting with B and changing from B to E in measure 4.

Comment: Is it a textbook example? Doesn't the textbook explain the notation?

Comment: yes it is, no explanation... thought it was too obvious

Comment: What book is it?  I've certainly never seen it before.  The "tenor a 10th above the bass" doesn't seem particularly likely, but I certainly can't think of any better possibilities.  In any event, the soprano would have to be a 17th above; being a 10th above the low G would be too low.